# Find the local truncation error of the exponential-Euler approximation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, truncation-error

**The Problem**

I have a differential equation of the following form $$\dot{y} = A(y)y+B(y)$$ Provided that $A$ does not depend on $y$ (or depends very weakly on $y$), I can approximate by using the following form: $$y(t)=e^{-At}y_0+\int^t_0e^{-(t-\tau)A}B(y)d\tau$$ Re-introducing the dependence of $A$ on $y$, the above can be discretised as follows:$$y_{k+1}=e^{-A(y_k)\Delta t}y_k + \Delta t\ \varphi_1(-\Delta t A)B(y_k)$$ where $\varphi_1(z) = \frac{e^z-z}{z}$ and $\Delta t$ is the time step.

I can confirm that the above approximation is accurate to make, since the result has been compared with another typical implicit solver, and the difference between the two is acceptable (nearly negligible).

**The Question**

However, my question is, can we get an expression for the local truncation error of the above? I have looked in [this paper](https://na.math.kit.edu/download/papers/acta-final.pdf), which extensively describes such type of integrators, however I can't seem to be able to understand how to obtain such an expression.

My thinking is that if I can estimate the local truncation error of the above, I can find a way to automatically adjust the timestep in accordance to my desired tolerances.

Comment: Exponential Euler is a first order method, to get the local truncation error just insert the analytical solution in the numerical scheme as you do for classical explicit Euler and other standard methods and it's done at page 223. Your intuition about adaptivity is correct, but as you can see in that paper, lotta things come into play in practice, as you will have usually (huge) matrix exponentials to compute, order conditions, and in general error estimator are all but easy to compute. Indeed you may find in the paper some references to other works where those estimators have been provided.